# what is the name of this computation?$e_{10}{(0.1)} = 0.8$

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics

section 1.4.3 of the book "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective" gives an example about KNN:

the input is two dimensional, we have three classes, and K = 10

[image]

[image]

[image]

which contains a computation

$e_{10}{(0.1)} = 0.8$

what does that mean? what is the name of this computation?

Comment: $0.1^{1/10} = 0.79432823472428150206591828283639$, because $e_{D}(f) = f^{1/D}$

Comment: @user158565 thanks man! plz mv your comments to answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Too short. Cannot be Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This section uses this formula to compute

> the expected edge length of this cube

$e_{D}(f) = f^{1/D}$

where, D = 10, so the original formula is $f^{1/10}$

> and we want to base our estimate on 10%

which means f = 10% = 0.1

put above together

$e_{D}(f) = f^{1/D} = 0.1^{1/10} = 0.79 \approx 0.8$

using "= 0.8" other than "$\approx 0.8$" in OP may confused you.